# Let's put a $\mathrm{Pin}$ in it$.$

Tags: condensed-matter, fermions, topology, spinors, topological-field-theory

As it turns out, the low-energy behaviour of (gapped) systems with fermionic degrees of freedom can be described by a so-called Spin TQFT. Such models require the introduction of a (S)pin structure. If the base manifold is non-trivial, the (S)pin structure is not in general unique, and different structures are physically inequivalent.

As long as we keep the discussion abstract, this all makes sense to me. But when I try to map these mathematical statements into real-life systems, nothing makes much sense anymore. If I have an actual physical system — say, a superconductor — that supports fermionic excitations, then the dynamics surely must be unique.

- What determines which (S)pin structure is the correct one? How do we know, a priori, which of the inequivalent structures is actually realised?
- (How) Can we modify a system so as to change the (S)pin structure (and nothing else, if possible)? What are the measurable differences we may observe before and after the change?